# App Engine Bulk Loader Performance

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, bulk-load, bulkloader

I am using the App Engine Bulk loader (Python Runtime) to bulk upload entities to the data store. The data that i am uploading is stored in a proprietary format, so i have implemented by own connector (registerd it in `bulkload_config.py`) to convert it to the intermediate python dictionary.

```
import google.appengine.ext.bulkload import connector_interface
class MyCustomConnector(connector_interface.ConnectorInterface):
   ....
   #Overridden method
   def generate_import_record(self, filename, bulkload_state=None):
      ....
      yeild my_custom_dict
```

To convert this neutral python dictionary to a datastore Entity, i use a custom post import function that i have defined in my YAML.

```
def feature_post_import(input_dict, entity_instance, bulkload_state):
    ....
    return [all_entities_to_put]
```

Note: I am not using `entity_instance, bulkload_state` in my `feature_post_import` function. I am just creating new data store entities (based on my `input_dict`), and returning them.

Now, everything works great. However, the process of bulk loading data seems to take way too much time. For e.g. a GB (~ 1,000,000 entities) of data takes ~ 20 hours. How can I improve the performance of the bulk load process. Am i missing something?

Some of the parameters that i use with appcfg.py are (10 threads with a batch size of 10 entities per thread).

Linked a Google App Engine Python group post: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/4c8def071a86c840

Update:
To test the performance of the Bulk Load process, I loaded `entities` of a 'Test' `Kind`. Even though this `entity` has a very simple `FloatProperty`, it still took me the same amount of time to bulk load those `entities`.

I am still going to try to vary the bulk loader parameters, `rps_limit`, `bandwidth_limit` and `http_limit`, to see if i can get any more throughput.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is parameter called `rps_limit` that determines the number of entities to upload per second. This was the major bottleneck. The default value for this is `20`.

Also increase the `bandwidth_limit` to something reasonable.

I increased `rps_limit` to `500` and everything improved. I achieved 5.5 - 6 seconds per 1000 entities which is a major improvement from 50 seconds per  1000 entities.